# How is T(n) of the code O(nlog(n))?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

I dont get the part where T(n) of the second for loop is log(n). Both loops are connected by 
i and it is confusing.How is T(n) of the code O(nlog(n)) using fundamental product rule?

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
   for(j = 1; j <= n; j = j + i)
   {
      printf("Hi");
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `j = j + i`

Comment: Yes j=j+i, How do we proceed with this. How to calculate T(n) for dependent loops?

Comment: Much similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863422/asymptotic-analysis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `i=1` inner loop executes `n` times. For `i=2` inner loop executes `n/2` times and so on. The running time is `T(n) = n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n`. This is equal to `n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...+ 1/n) = nH(n)` where `H(n)` is the nth harmonic number. `H(n) ~ lg n` hence the running time of `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: Awesome!! But can u help me out how to do the problem using product rule of finding T(n)? @saadtaame

Comment: That's a product! The second factor is just a bit different than what you are used to. If inner loop executed `m` times for example you would write `m + m + ... + m`, `m` appears `n` times. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)  // Executes n times
{    
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j = j + i)
    {   // This loop executes j times with j increases by rate of i
        printf(“Hi”);
    }
}
```

The inner loop executes `n/i` times for each value of `i`. Its running time is `nxSum(n/i)` for all `i` in  [1,n]

=> `O(nlogn)`