# Time Complexity of Programs

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am just learning about time complexity, here is piece of code I've written

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
  for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
  {
    // Spread Peace
  }
```

Clearly the above one is of **O(N^2)** complexity and its seems (for `N == 1e6`) to run forever.

Here is second piece of code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
  for (int j = i; j <= N; j++)
  {
    // Money is Everything
  }
```

the above one is also **O(N^2) - N*(N+1)/2** complexity is also running forever, but this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
  for (int j = i; j <= N; j += i)
  {
    // Be my GirlFriend
  }
```

just executes within a sec., I am not able to derive its time complexity why this so fast? What's is the *estimation* for `N == 1e6`?

Comment: I suggest you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation and understand the meaning of the symbol and what it denotes. It will solve your doubt too.

Answer (score 4):

Let's carry out an *experiment* first, let's try *unrolling* the loop (*C# implementation*) and have a look what's going on:

```
 private static IEnumerable<String> Unroll(int N) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int j = i; j <= N; j += i) {
      if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Append(", ");

      sb.Append(j);
    }

    yield return sb.ToString();
  }
```

A test run with a small number (e.g. `16`) reveals the picture

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Unroll(16)));
```

Can you see the pattern, an *exponential* drop? It looks like `N * log(N)`, right?

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16
3, 6, 9, 12, 15
4, 8, 12, 16
5, 10, 15
6, 12
7, 14
8, 16
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Now it's time for the paper and pencil: we have (for large `N`)

```
   N / 1 items (step == 1) +
   N / 2 items (step == 2) +
   N / 3 items (step == 3) +
   ...
   N / N items (step == N)
------------------------------
   N * (1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/N) = 
   N * H(N) = 
   O(N * log(N)) // Harmonic sum H(N) gives log(N)
```

More accurate estimation

```
   H(N) = ln(N) + gamma + 1/(2*N) + ...
```

where

```
   ln()  - natural logarithm
   gamma - Euler–Mascheroni constant (0.5772156649...)
```

gives you for `N == 1e6` about `14.4e6` loops which is, in fact, a bit *overestimated*; the actual count is `13970034` (`14.0e6`) since  when aproximating with Harmonic series we did't take *integer division* (each `k/N` should be *integer*, i.e. not `k/N`, but `floor(k/N)`) into account.

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed using Sigma notation:

[image]

More on Harmonic functions here: [Asymptotic analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863422/asymptotic-analysis/23071256)